# Rails Controller render json. I need to include nil values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have the following models in my rails App.

- Lease
- Estate
- Contact
- Address

> ```
> class Lease < ApplicationRecord
>   belongs_to :estate
>   belongs_to :contact
> end
>
> class Contact < ApplicationRecord
>   has_one :address
> end
> ```

```
      lease.as_json(include: [:estate, {contact: {:include => :address}} ])
```

And this is the generated json when `contact.address` is not null:

```
{
id: 1,
start_date: "2019-05-09",
end_date: "2019-05-09",
title: "test title",
description: "test desc",
estate_id: 10,
contact_id: 4,
estate: {
    id: 10,
    address: "Address here",
    lat: 37.0322021,
    lng: 22.11332570000002,
},
contact: {
    id: 1,
    full_name: "contact name goes here",
    address: {
          title: 'this is the address'
       }
    }
}
```

What I need is not to hide the 'address' field from the json whenever it is null (which is the default process).

In other words, when the `contact.address` is nil, I need the following json result:

```
{
    id: 1,
    start_date: "2019-05-09",
    end_date: "2019-05-09",
    title: "test title",
    description: "test desc",
    estate_id: 10,
    contact_id: 4,
    estate: {
        id: 10,
        address: "Address here",
        lat: 37.0322021,
        lng: 22.11332570000002,
    },
    contact: {
        id: 1,
        full_name: "contact name goes here",
        address: {
              title: ''
           }
        }
    }
```

Notice that I need the address field to be there, but with no value.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a `nil` value like a standard attribute. Contact has_one Address so there needs to be a record in the database or the instance has to have been joined to an unpersisted object (below) if you are going to use `as_json`.

I have two ideas for how to approach this, but first I'm a bit surprised at this part of your data:

```
contact: {
    id: 1,
    full_name: "contact name goes here",
    address: {
          title: 'this is the address'
       }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's at the root of your problem, but are you sure you didn't hand code this? I would expect an address.id to be present:

```
contact: {
    id: 1,
    full_name: "contact name goes here",
    address: {
         id: 1,
         title: 'this is the address'
       }
    }
}
```

My **first suggestion** would be something like

```
lease.contact.address = Address.new unless lease.contact.address
```

This will probably get what you want, but I haven't tested it.

My **second suggestion** would be to consider using a formal serializer to get another layer of logic and processing between your active model records and your JSON. You can define "attributes" that are computed in methods.

I have had good results with [fast_jsonapi](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi)